# How to change the default icon on the SearchView, to be use in the action bar on Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm having a bit of  trouble customizing the search icon in the SearchView. On my point of view, the icon can be changed in the Item attributes, right? Just check the code bellow..

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is the menu I'm using, with my custom search icon **icn_lupa**. But when I run the app, I always get the default search icon...

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
      android:title="@string/menu_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/icn_lupa"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Comment: I think @just_user 's answer should be marked the correct. Please review. :)

Comment: Recent support library `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` can be styled with `app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_your_custom_icon"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the actionViewClass overides the icon and it doesn't look like you can change it from [this class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html).

You got two solutions:

- Live with it and I think it's the best option in terms of user experience and platform conformity.
- [Define your own actionViewClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446126/custom-action-view-cant-be-clicked)

Comment: Yeah... you are right... actually my search icon was very similar to the default widget icon, but more similar with the rest of icons used in the app.

Answer (score 100):

I've found another way to change the search icon which goes in the same line as Diego Pino's answer but straight in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`.

In your menu.xml (same as before)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_fav"
      android:title="@string/action_websearch"
      android:showAsAction="always|never"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

In  your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem searchViewMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);    
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchViewMenuItem.getActionView();
    int searchImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
    ImageView v = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_new_icon); 
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I followed the example for changing the edittext in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget/11669808#11669808).

You should be able to do this for all icons/backgrounds in your `SearchView`, to find the right ID you can check [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/widget/SearchView.java/#248).

**UPDATE November 2017:**

Since this answer android has been updated with the possibility of changing the search icon through the XML.

If you target anything below android v21 you can use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp" />
```

Or v21 and later:

```
<SearchView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp" />
```

And there are even more options:

```
closeIcon
commitIcon
goIcon
searchHintIcon
searchIcon
voiceIcon
```

Comment: Using identifier "android:id/search_button" is a great idea! I couldn't find it anywhere else. Thank your very much for the answer!!!

Comment: Brilliant - searched high and low and tried many things before finding your solution - thanks!

Comment: thanks but when my searchview is expanded still uses the system icon. any idea?

Comment: Update Hint with SpannableStringBuilder. Copied following from android source, SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("   "); // for the icon
        ssb.append(hintText);
        Drawable searchIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.search_or);
        int textSize = (int) (searchTextView.getTextSize() * 1.25);
        searchIcon.setBounds(0, 0, textSize, textSize);
        ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(searchIcon), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        searchTextView.setHint(ssb);

Comment: updated answer shows preview in android studio properly, but when I run app it doesn't show effect at runtime. Strange....

Comment: I don't get how to use your updated version, could you also share with us your `menu.xml` too?

Comment: using getIdentifier helped me to solve the problem thanks :)

Answer (score 37):

Nice answer from @just_user

For my case, since I am using the appcompat v7 library for the SearchView + ActionBar, i modified his solution a bit to make it compatible to my project, it should work so as long as you did not modify anything when you added appcompat v7 as library

XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:metrodeal="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >


    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/search"
        metrodeal:showAsAction="always"
        metrodeal:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" 
        android:icon="@drawable/search_btn"/>

</menu>
```

Java code:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem searchViewMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.main_menu_action_search);
    SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchViewMenuItem);
    int searchImgId = android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button; // I used the explicit layout ID of searchview's ImageView
    ImageView v = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_btn);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Excuse for the very big icon (I have not resized the icon just yet), but it should work as it is.

[image]

Comment: I did the the same for sherlock library and it worked. Thanks.


`MenuItem searchViewMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);  
 SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView)  searchViewMenuItem.getActionView();
ImageView v = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(com.actionbarsherlock.R.id.abs__search_button);`
      v.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);

Comment: For androidx: `androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_button`. And fix the ImageView scaling with `v.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);`

Answer (score 21):

I was struggling with this too but then I accidentaly used 'collapseActionView' and that fixed it!
My menu.xml looks like this now:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
      android:title="@string/menu_search"
      android:showAsAction="always|withText|collapseActionView"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" /> 
</menu>
```

The downside of this is that on tablets the SearchView will appear on the left side of the ActionBar instead of where the searchicon is, but I don't mind that.

Comment: I tried this and it really doesn't work. After expanding the searchview, pressing the back button does not properly dismiss it. Instead the old icon appears on the left side of the actionbar. It takes a second press of the backbutton to properly hide it.

Comment: It works for me on my test device (SM-G925V) but I'm not sure how many other devices will have strange behaviors like Kyle Ivey had. I do have the same behavior that Mathieu Post said about the search being on the left instead of the right but that's likely because I do not know the collapseActionView's intended purpose.

Answer (score 15):

I defined a style to do it .

here is my xml:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/sv_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        **style="@style/CitySearchView"**
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and this is my style:

```
<style name="CitySearchView" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_more_search</item>
</style>
```

That it！

After finish that，just take a look at Base.Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.SearchView" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="layout">@layout/abc_search_view</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@drawable/abc_textfield_search_material</item>
    <item name="submitBackground">@drawable/abc_textfield_search_material</item>
    <item name="closeIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha</item>
    <item name="goIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_go_search_api_mtrl_alpha</item>
    <item name="voiceIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_voice_search_api_mtrl_alpha</item>
    <item name="commitIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_commit_search_api_mtrl_alpha</item>
    <item name="suggestionRowLayout">@layout/abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line</item>
</style>
```

every item can be override by define a new style .

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 14):

There's a way to do this. The trick is to recover the ImageView using its identifier and setting a new image with `setImageResource()`. This solution is inspired on [Changing the background drawable of the searchview widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget).

```
private SearchView searchbox;

private void customizeSearchbox() {
    setSearchHintIcon(R.drawable.new_search_icon);
}

private void setSearchHintIcon(int resourceId) {
    ImageView searchHintIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(searchbox, 
        "android:id/search_mag_icon");
    searchHintIcon.setImageResource(resourceId);
}

private View findViewById(View v, String id) {
    return v.findViewById(v.getContext().getResources().
        getIdentifier(id, null, null));        
}
```

Comment: To clarify, this is to change the default icon when the search view is "expanded."

Comment: Thank you I could change the icon.

Answer (score 6):

SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.address_search);

```
    try {
        Field searchField = SearchView.class
                .getDeclaredField("mSearchButton");
        searchField.setAccessible(true);
        ImageView searchBtn = (ImageView) searchField.get(searchView);
        searchBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_glass);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is not working when search widget expands :(

Answer (score 5):

After some research I found the solution [here](http://nlopez.io/how-to-style-the-actionbar-searchview-programmatically/). The trick is that the icon is not in an `ImageView` but in the `Spannable` object.

```
// Accessing the SearchAutoComplete
int queryTextViewId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);  
View autoComplete = searchView.findViewById(queryTextViewId);

Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete");

SpannableStringBuilder stopHint = new SpannableStringBuilder("   ");  
stopHint.append(getString(R.string.your_new_text));

// Add the icon as an spannable
Drawable searchIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search);  
Method textSizeMethod = clazz.getMethod("getTextSize");  
Float rawTextSize = (Float)textSizeMethod.invoke(autoComplete);  
int textSize = (int) (rawTextSize * 1.25);  
searchIcon.setBounds(0, 0, textSize, textSize);  
stopHint.setSpan(new ImageSpan(searchIcon), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Set the new hint text
Method setHintMethod = clazz.getMethod("setHint", CharSequence.class);  
setHintMethod.invoke(autoComplete, stopHint);
```

Answer (score 5):

In menu xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_filter"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_filter"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_filter"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_filter"/>
```

and create the `layout/menu_filter`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SearchView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_filter"/>
```

then in activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu` or `onPrepareOptionsMenu`:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_filter).getActionView();
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

Comment: Btw, use `app:actionLayout` instead of `android:actionLayout` if you want to call `getActionView`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<SearchView
            android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
..../>
```

use the searchIcon xml tag

Answer (score 3):

This works with Material Design (MaterialComponents theme) and BottomAppBar.

If you are using androidx library, for example:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

You can create a method and invoke it from wherever you want:

```
  /**
 * Set SearchView Icon
 * @param i Drawable icon
 */
private void setSVIcon(int i) {
    ImageView iv = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
    iv.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), i, null));
}
```

Usage example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(m, menu);
    MenuItem mn = menu.findItem(R.id.sv);
    if (mn != null) {
        searchview = (SearchView) mn.getActionView();
        setSVIcon(R.drawable.ic_sr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update hint of AutocompleteTextView for updating search icon in the expanded mode, copied from android source,

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();
        int searchImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
        ImageView v = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
        v.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_or);

        int searchTextViewId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        AutoCompleteTextView searchTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(searchTextViewId);
        searchTextView.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.hint_color_white));
        searchTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        searchTextView.setTextSize(18.0f);


        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("   "); // for the icon
        ssb.append(hintText);
        Drawable searchIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.search_or);
        int textSize = (int) (searchTextView.getTextSize() * 1.25);
        searchIcon.setBounds(0, 0, textSize, textSize);
        ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(searchIcon), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        searchTextView.setHint(ssb);


        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: any idea on how to change the close icon also ?

Answer (score 1):

From API 21 you can change it in xml:

```
android:searchIcon="@drawable/loupe"
android:closeIcon="@drawable/x_white"
```

Comment: This also works with current compat library below api level 21 (just tested searchIcon). SearchView within Toolbar and AppCompat Library v7:23

Answer (score 1):

for  api level < 21, i did this:

```
        int searchImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
    ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
    if(ivIcon!=null)
        ivIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search);
```

from this

[image]

to this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are three magnifying glass icons. two of them are shown when IconizedByDefault is true(one which is shown before pressing and one is shown in the "hint") and one is shown all the time when IconizedByDefault is false. all the fields are private so the way to get them is by their xml id. (most of the code is mentioned  separately in other answers in this post already)

when IconizedByDefault is true change the icon in the hint (which is seen only after pressing the icon) by :

```
mSearchSrcTextView = (SearchAutoComplete)findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
```

then do the same as in the android source code:

```
final int textSize = (int) (mSearchSrcTextView.getTextSize() * 1.25);
    newSearchIconDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, textSize, textSize);

    final SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("   ");
    ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(newSearchIconDrawable), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ssb.append(hintText);
```

mSearchHintIcon was replaced with newSearchIconDrawable which is your new search icon. 
Then set the hint with

```
mSearchSrcTextView.setHint(ssb);
```

The other 2 icons are in an `ImageView`, which can be found by their Id.
for the icon when searchview is closed (when iconizedByDefault is true) do:

```
mSearchButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
```

and for the one that always appears (if iconizedByDefault is false)

```
mCollapsedIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon);
```

Answer (score 1):

Desperate solution using Kotlin

```
    val s = (searchView.getAllChildren().firstOrNull() as? LinearLayout)?.getAllChildren()?.filter { it is AppCompatImageView }?.firstOrNull() as? AppCompatImageView
    s?.setImageResource(R.drawable.search)
```

getAllChildren:

```
fun ViewGroup.getAllChildren() : ArrayList<View> {
val views = ArrayList<View>()
for (i in 0..(childCount-1)) {
    views.add(getChildAt(i))
}
return views
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
Use two menu xml files. In one of the xmls the menu item has an actionView and in the other one no. Initially inflate the collapsed menu and when the menu item is clicked, invalidate the menu and inflate the expanded menu xml and make sure you call setIconified(false);

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    if(!mShowSearchView)
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_collapsed, menu);
    }
    else
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_expanded, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose()
            {
                mShowSearchView = false;
                ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(getActivity());
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_filter)
    {
        menu.showMenu();
    }
    else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_search)
    {
        mShowSearchView = true;
        ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(getActivity());
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just name your icon the same name as the icon that is used by the search view. When it compiles it takes the resource in the project over the icon in the library.

Answer (score -1):

I use the AppCompat library. Yes, specifying `android:icon="@drawable/search_icon_png"` doesnt work.
So i looked into the source code of @style/Theme.AppCompat and found the icon that android uses.

```
<item name="searchViewSearchIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_search</item>
```

So if you rename your search icon inside your drawables to `abc_ic_search.png`, this icon is rendered as its found in your app drawable first, rather than the appcompat drawable folder.
Works for me :)

Using this approach you can customize the close and clear icons for the search widget as well.