# How to change the search icon of searchview android

Tags: android, searchview

I want to change the default search icon of searchview.
I have tried the below things :

```
int searchImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
    ImageView searchIconView = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
    if(searchIconView != null){
        searchIconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_clear_white);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        searchIconView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

But It is not changing the search icon at all, how can I do this. I have checked other links also and tried the solutions given but that also not working in my case.

[How to change the default icon on the SearchView, to be use in the action bar on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445760/how-to-change-the-default-icon-on-the-searchview-to-be-use-in-the-action-bar-on)

Please help if anyone have idea here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14375746/3790150

Answer (score 0):

Make a menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".screens.MoviesScreen">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        app:showAsAction="always" />    

</menu>
```

You can specify any drawable of your choice in the android:icon property

in the activity, inflate the menu

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
    app:searchIcon="@drawable/my_search_icon"
    app:voiceIcon="@drawable/my_voice_search_icon"
    app:closeIcon="@drawable/my_close_icon"
    app:commitIcon="@drawable/my_commit_icon"
    app:goIcon="@drawable/my_go_icon"
    app:searchHintIcon="@drawable/my_search_hint_icon"/>
```