# My own image in the place of search icon in the searchView

Tags: android, searchview

I am designing an application where I need my own searchIcon in the following format

[image]

here the first one in the picture is the default search View and the second one is that what i Want i.e. my own image and when we expand it should be
[image]

in the above format

I took different codes from internet but no code gave me the exact solution.
Could SomeOne help me please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18360563/1944782 please refer this answer. It will solve your problem.