# Change the icons of Search in Actionbar

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

I added a search to the Action bar by using the following code:

activity_main_actions.xml

```
<!-- Search  -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>


<!-- Add -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_add_tip"
      android:icon="@drawable/header_add"
      android:title="@string/action_add_tip"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<!-- Count -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_count_tip"
      android:icon="@drawable/header_count"
      android:title="@string/action_count_tip"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        // search action
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

searchable.xml

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        // search action
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.emy.healthytips.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The search is working well with me, but the icon of the search in Action bar is still as it "Gray icon" like the following ScreenShot, although I added my own icon in 
    `<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"`

How can I add my own icon?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question ma be related with your problem. Please check it.

[How to change the default icon on the SearchView, to be use in the action bar on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445760/how-to-change-the-default-icon-on-the-searchview-to-be-use-in-the-action-bar-on)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the second answer in your link is helped me.

Comment: But I have another question, if the id of the search icon is: `searchImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);` what is the id of the icon that close the search bar?

Comment: In searchable tag for search configuration, there is a tag named icon. You can use it to set your own.