# Change SearchView's close icon to loading icon on suggestion query

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, searchview

I have a SearchView in my actionbar with suggestions enabled via a cursor adapter.
How can we change the default close icon on SearchView to a loading icon when we perform filterig on the suggestionsAdapter?

Comment: With the loading animation or just the icon ?

Comment: see 4th answer in this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445760/how-to-change-the-default-icon-on-the-searchview-to-be-use-in-the-action-bar-on)