# Can you remove back button after search view has been clicked (expanded)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have one activity with action bar. Action bar contains search view. I don't want that back button which appears when search view is clicked. Is it possible to remove it or hide it? That back button is not visible until I click the search view. By the way the following line of code doesn't help.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

[image]

Menu resource

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the default icon on the SearchView, to be use in the action bar on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445760/how-to-change-the-default-icon-on-the-searchview-to-be-use-in-the-action-bar-on)

Comment: @xenteros it is not a duplicate. Clearly this want to remove back button and the other want to change search icon.

Answer (score 7):

I have been dealing with a similar issue. To simply remove the arrow, I changed `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"` to `app:showAsAction="always"`.
However, now I have a blank space instead of the arrow, which is an issue I have yet to resolve.

Comment: It doesn't hide anything and I have never had `collapseActionView` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410048/searchview-in-expanded-mode-doesnt-hide-all-action-bar-icons-starting-from-mars

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem and fixed it by setting the

**app:collapseIcon**

attribute in the toolbar.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbarHeight"
         app:collapseIcon="@drawable/collapseBackIcon" />
```

Comment: what exactly is "@drawable/collapseBackIcon"? Seems that's important to the solution

Comment: @sbearben It's not, just any random drawable you want to use :)