# Android: SearchView component change icon (no ActionBar)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, searchview

How can I change default search icon for SearchView?

```
<SearchView
   android:id="@+id/searchView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I´m not using actionBar. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s possible to use AppCompat.

But I used small hack:

```
mSearchView = (SearchView) searchViewMenuItem.getActionView();
int searchImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
ImageView v = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
v.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_new_icon);
```

from this [How to change the default icon on the SearchView, to be use in the action bar on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445760/how-to-change-the-default-icon-on-the-searchview-to-be-use-in-the-action-bar-on?lq=1) and it looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchView</item>
</style>

<style name="MySearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_search</item>
    <item name="closeIcon">@drawable/ic_close</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I´m using this theme @android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.