# How to customize the search icon on toolbar in android?

Tags: android

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        appcompat:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

I want to change the [search image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M4Km.jpg) in the top right corner, currently it is black and I want to change it to orange

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445760/how-to-change-the-default-icon-on-the-searchview-to-be-use-in-the-action-bar-on

Comment: currently it is black. This is a image have colour black. You must create a image have colour orange. and replace it !!!

Comment: Already tried it, but not working

Comment: please post your code for better answers

Comment: The black image is the default image, I have already added an orange image in the menu.xml file. But still black image is showing.

Comment: Plz, show your code menu.xml

Comment: make sure you use  android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_orange"

Comment: This  image is the orange image which I want to show to show but isn't working android:icon="@drawable/search"

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_notifications, menu);
            this.menu = menu;
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_clear_all) {
                showToast("Clear All");
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Create xml file under res>menu.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".YourActivityName" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_clear_all"
        android:title="@string/noti_clear_all"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_clear_all"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the color of your MenuItem by `setColorFilter`.

Drawable can be changed to any color.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_menu_frag, menu);
    // replace MenuItem with your own
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(0);
    final Drawable drawable = item.getIcon();
    if (drawable != null) {
        final int color = Color.RED;
        drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` you can use this:
Note: You may want to use `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN` instead of `PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY`)

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
int color = 0; // SPECIFY THE COLOUR YOU WANT HERE. I suggest you retrieve colour from colors.xml
menuItem.getIcon().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

But personally I would probably just change the colour of the drawable manually (i.e. replace the drawable with a coloured one).

Answer (score 0):

Use below XML in your menu item

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/menu_search" />
```

// Please make sure you using same menu item xml in your activity or fragment.