# Defined menu icon not showing when using SearchView

Tags: android, searchview, android-menu

I have my menu item using SearchView as below.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

I wanted my own icon, where the icon should be `@android:drawable/ic_menu_search` as indicated in my xml. When I run it, it still use back it's default icon.

How could I get my menu icon instead of the default one provided by SearchView?

**Update** to clarify my question.

If I remove `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`, it will then show the `android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"` as per what I wanted.

But if I put `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` up, it will not show `android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"`, but replace with whatever the SearchView provided.

I don't want use the icon SearchView provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

same as for all icons and images in drawable folder and use  `android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"`

Comment: I actually wanted `@android:drawable/ic_menu_search` as my icon. But it is not showing `@android:drawable/ic_menu_search`.

Comment: It is there. I have updated my question to make it clearer.

Comment: may be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445760/how-to-change-the-default-icon-on-the-searchview-to-be-use-in-the-action-bar-on

Comment: Yes, the above link helps. Thanks!

Comment: If the above link gives the answer, it should be used to mark this post as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing ifroom to always `app:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not asking about why the icon is not shown. The icon is shown, but not the icon I stated.