# Change color of android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

I am using search view.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewMenu"
            >
  </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
```

Is this possible to change text color and icon color to view?

Currently it shows black text and icon. I want to change it to white color text and white search icon.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This may work..

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
EditText searchEditText = (EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Comment: thanks it will change text color to white.. icon is still black

Comment: You may change icon runtime or as per answer of naveen

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445760/how-to-change-the-default-icon-on-the-searchview-to-be-use-in-the-action-bar-on

Comment: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView has not method "setTextColor"

Comment: For AndroidX use androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_text

Answer (score 7):

For the android.support.v7.widget.SearchView  you can change the text color, text hint color and the icon with this code :

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_action_search);
    SearchView searchViewAction = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());

    searchViewAction.setSearchableInfo(searchableInfo);
    searchViewAction.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    EditText searchEditText = (EditText)searchViewAction.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

    ImageView searchMagIcon = (ImageView)searchViewAction.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
    searchMagIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search_white);


    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To Change the Text color :

```
int searchSrcTextId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);  
EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(searchSrcTextId);  
searchEditText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);  
searchEditText.setHintTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
```

To Change the close button :

```
int closeButtonId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);  
ImageView closeButtonImage = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(closeButtonId);  
closeButtonImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel);
```

// This excerpt is from Android source code (SearchView.java)

```
mSearchButton = findViewById(R.id.search_button);  
mSearchEditFrame = findViewById(R.id.search_edit_frame);  
mSearchPlate = findViewById(R.id.search_plate);  
mSubmitArea = findViewById(R.id.submit_area);  
mSubmitButton = findViewById(R.id.search_go_btn);  
mCloseButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);  
mVoiceButton = findViewById(R.id.search_voice_btn);  
mSearchHintIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon);
```

Reference : [link](http://nlopez.io/how-to-style-the-actionbar-searchview-programmatically/)

Comment: tried .. not working. for change icon it is possible to change color without set image view?

Answer (score 5):

If it resides in toolbar, set theme for toolbar. For example this makes the text(and icon) white

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/LightGray</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/LightGray</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/TransparentGray</item>
</style>
```

apply this theme to your toolbar hint that (colorControlHighlight) color of ripple effct of your menu items

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it, one of ways to do it:

```
public static void customizeSearchView(SearchView searchView) {

        int searchTextViewId = searchView.getContext().getResources()
                .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        AutoCompleteTextView searchTextView
                = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(searchTextViewId);
        searchTextView.setTextSize(14);
        searchTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```